# fail2ban-regex matches with strings, but not with log and conf files, why?

Tags: regex, fail2ban

If I run

```
fail2ban-regex '31.22.105.115 - - [11/Apr/2014:18:09:54 +0100] "GET /admin/config.php 
HTTP/1.0" 301 573 "-" "-"' '^<HOST> - - (?:\[[^]]*\] )+\"(GET|POST)/(?i)(PMA|phptest|phpmyadmin|myadmin|mysql|mysqladmin|sqladmin|mypma|admin|xampp|mysqldb|mydb|db|pmadb|phpmyadmin1|phpmyadmin2|cgi-bin)'
```

Then I get `Success, the total number of match is 1`. Yet If I have an `access.log` containing

```
 .
 .
109.68.191.26 - - [11/Apr/2014:12:47:50 +0100] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 301 541 "-" "masscan/1.0 (https://github.com/robertdavidgraham/masscan)"
31.22.105.115 - - [11/Apr/2014:18:09:54 +0100] "GET /admin/config.php HTTP/1.0" 301 573 "-" "-"
```

and a `filter.d` .conf file containing

```
failregex  = '^<HOST> - - (?:\[[^]]*\] )+\"(GET|POST) /(?i)(PMA|phptest|phpmyadmin|myadmin|mysql|mysqladmin|sqladmin|mypma|admin|xampp|mysqldb|mydb|db|pmadb|phpmyadmin1|phpmyadmin2|cgi-bin)'
```

, and I try running `fail2ban-regex path/to/access.log /etc/fail2ban/filter.d/apache-getphp.conf` I get `Sorry, no match`, why?

Answer (score 3):

Ah, simply that I shouldn't quote the regex in the filter.d file, i.e, should be:

```
failregex  = ^<HOST> - - (?:\[[^]]*\] )+\"(GET|POST) /(?i)(PMA|phptest|phpmyadmin|myadmin|mysql|mysqladmin|sqladmin|mypma|admin|xampp|mysqldb|mydb|db|pmadb|phpmyadmin1|phpmyadmin2|cgi-bin)
```